# How to use Skulpt to eval Python line by line

Tags: javascript, python, interpreter, skulpt

The example given by [Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/) runs the interpreter on the whole string containing the python program:

https://github.com/skulpt/skulpt/blob/master/example/calling_from_js.html

Is there a possibility to run the interpreter line by line, for example in order to highlight the Python line which is currently executed?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
var program = "print('something')\nprint('something else')";

var programs = program.split("\n");

for(var i = 0; i<programs.length; i++){
    //skulpt on `programs[i]` and highlight that line
}
```

Essentially you just want to do something like this:

1. Split the full program into a series of lines
2. Run each line through Skulpt individually (highlight this line as needed)

Slightly modified code from your second link:

```
<script src="../dist/skulpt.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function outf(text)
    {
        var output = document.getElementById("output");
        text = text.replace(/</g, '&lt;');
        output.innerHTML = output.innerHTML + text;
    }
    function runit(prog)
    {
        //changed this so the function accepts an argument
        var output = document.getElementById("output");
        output.innerHTML = '';
        Sk.configure({output:outf});
        try {
            var module = Sk.importMainWithBody("<stdin>", false, prog);
            var obj = module.tp$getattr('a');
            var runMethod = obj.tp$getattr('run');
            var ret = Sk.misceval.callsim(runMethod, 10);
            alert(ret.v);
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }
</script>
<form>
<textarea id="code" rows="24" cols="80">
class Test:
     def run(self, b):
         self.a = 10 + b
         return self.a

print "Hello World"
a = Test()
</textarea><br>
<button onclick="runit()" type="button">Run</button>
</form>

<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Then just insert this code wherever you want

```
var programs = document.getElementById("code").value;

for(var i = 0; i<programs.length; i++){
    // Whatever code you want to use to highlight the line goes here
    runit(programs[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. The way to call skulpt on the given line interest me particularily. Can I call Sk.importMainWithBody() on each line keeping the context?

Comment: From the second link you can see the `runit` function, right? That will execute the program in the variable `prog`. So just change the variable `prog` to the variable you want to run (in this case `programs[i]`). Maybe if you want you can change the function to accept a string to run rather than getting the string from the HTML and you should be good. Does that make sense?

Comment: I just tried your sample and it's not working. Many messages about undefined objects. I'm not sure but probably it's because the skulpt stack is somehow reinit.